# keep leading spaces when reading strings into pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, whitespace

I have a csv that I am trying to load into pandas. There are three columns in the csv, separated by a pipe. The first 2 columns are integers and the third column is a string. There are irregularities in the data such that some strings start with a space and some do not. I am in the situation where I **must** preserve those leading white spaces for a later processing step, however, it appears that pandas strips it. any help would be much appreciated!

example data:

```
1|2|Dogs are better than cats!
1|4| Cats are superior to dogs.    
2|3|Birds Rule. More than you think! #birdsrule
2|10|Birds birds birds
```

I have tried both the read_csv function and building my own parser, both to no avail. Here are my attempts:

read_csv:

```
my_df=pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="|", dtype=str, names=['num1','num2','some_Text'], encoding = 'utf8', skipinitialspace=False)
```

my own parser:

```
my_df = []

with open("foo.txt", "r") as data:
    for row in data:
        num1, num2, some_text = row.split("|")
        some_text = some_text.strip("\n")
        my_df.append(
            pd.DataFrame({
                "num1": [num1],
                "num2": [num2],
                "some_text": [some_text]
            })
        )
my_df = pd.concat(my_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work just fine.

```
In [17]: df = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="|", dtype=str, names=['num1','num2','some_Text'], encoding = 'utf8', skipinitialspace=False)

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
  num1 num2                                    some_Text
0    1    2                   Dogs are better than cats!
1    1    4                   Cats are superior to dogs.
2    2    3  Birds Rule. More than you think! #birdsrule
3    2   10                            Birds birds birds

In [19]: df.values
Out[19]: 
array([['1', '2', 'Dogs are better than cats!'],
       ['1', '4', ' Cats are superior to dogs.'],
       ['2', '3', 'Birds Rule. More than you think! #birdsrule'],
       ['2', '10', 'Birds birds birds']], dtype=object)
```

Note that the space before Cats is preserved, although since the string columns are right-justified, you might be fooled into thinking otherwise.

```
In [24]: df["some_Text"][1]
Out[24]: ' Cats are superior to dogs.'
```

It should also work, and treat the types appropriately (having num1 and num2 become ints, I mean) with a simpler call, namely `pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="|", names=['num1','num2','some_Text'])`.

Answer (score 2):

I show that it works... whats more is that `skipinitialspace=False` is the default.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """1|2|Dogs are better than cats!
1|4| Cats are superior to dogs.    
2|3|Birds Rule. More than you think! #birdsrule
2|10|Birds birds birds
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|', header=None)

# get first character of third column
df.iloc[:, 2].str[0]

0    D
1     
2    B
3    B
Name: 2, dtype: object
```